# Flutter: How to verify textfield characters with maxLength property

Tags: flutter

I want to verify **textfield** characters with maxLength property which I assigned to the widget.

I used below code to assign maxLength

```
TextField field = new TextField(
      autofocus: true,
      maxLength: 4,
);
```

Is there any way to get this maxLength value to verify the entered characters with maxLength property?

Comment: Verification purpose as in? Your question is not clear, do you want to check whether the length is equal to maxLength and perform some action accordingly?

Comment: @Alok: right, Also I edited the question for more understanding

Comment: Added an answer, let me know if that works for you (fingers crossed) :)

Comment: So... you want to get the max length value, `4` in this case, and check if the user has entered 4 characters?

Answer (score 2):

I found the simple way of doing this

```
   TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
   controller.addListener(() {
      if(controller.text.length == field.maxLength) { // TextField field = new TextField
        print("User trying to add more characters");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Need some GlobalKey inside TextField**

```dart
ListTile(
  title: Text(
    "Some Random Field",
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
  subtitle: TextField(
    key: _keyTextField, // add some key here
    maxLength: 4,
  ),
),
```

**2. Get maxLength value by exploring currentWidget values**

```dart
  void handleButton() {
    int maxLength = getMaxLength();
    print("maxLength : $maxLength");
  }

  int getMaxLength() {
    String properties = _keyTextField.currentWidget.toString();
    RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'(maxLength: )\d+');
    RegExpMatch matches = exp.firstMatch(properties);
    if (matches != null && matches.groupCount > 0) {
      String maxLengthStrings = matches.group(0);
      return int.parse(maxLengthStrings.split("maxLength: ").last);
    } else {
      print("Not found");
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

#### Demo

[image: Demo]

#### Full Code Repo

You may look into TextFieldScreen widget here. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/f_screen/text_field.dart)